# Is something wrong with the way JavaScript reads arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

Newbie here. 
I have the code:

```
var fanta = "Fantastic";
fanta.substring (0,4);
```

It prints the result: "Fant", but shouldn't it be "Fanta", since arrays start at 0? 
I just used the JavaScript console for this.

Comment: At which point does your string become an array?

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) is always useful. "_**indexEnd**: ...  the offset into the string of the first character not to include in the returned substring._"

Answer (score 3):

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring), `substring()` in JavaScript is `(startIndex, endIndex)`, and the arguments are inclusive and exclusive respectively.

So the substring will include index 0 but not index 4.

Comment: Of cooooouuurse. "Fanta" is from index 0 to 4, but saying (0, 5) stops it at index 5?

Comment: Yes. `"Fantastic".substring(0, 5)` would return `Fanta`. Starts at index 0 and goes to index `5 - 1` (so 4).

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is the end of the returned substring, but it is not included in the return. See: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs for substring state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) regarding the second parameter:

> An integer between 0 and the length of the string, which specifies the
>   offset into the string of the first character not to include in the
>   returned substring.

So `substring (0,4)` starts at the first character and grabs all the characters up to, *but not including*, the character at position 4.